# How to build and compile visual studio c++ code from command prompt window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild

I have written a c++ code in visual studio 2013. I want to build and compile the code from command prompt window. Can someone suggest me how to perform this operation. Thanks

Comment: You should google it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I know the only way to to that is the following:

```
devenv.exe yousolution.sln /Build "Release"
```

devenv must be in path (usually something like PROGRAMFILES\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe") and you have to specify the configuration (Release in this example, but can be Debug or any other configuration).

Comment: Thanks Marom for your reply. I tried the way you suggested but I'm not getting any output from the command line window...I followed the below steps:
1. Opened the command prompt window 
2. I entered cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\
3. Then I gave devenv.exe MatchTest.sln /Build "Debug" and enter
After enter I didn't get any error message or output message.

My question is since my MatchTest.sln project is at different location how it will be executed when I give above commands.

Comment: Yes, there is no output, which in case of errors is a problem. I use it in automated build, where I know everything is OK. When there is a problem I need to fire up the IDE.

Comment: The usual way is to use msbuild instead of going round via devenv (which will use msbuild ultimately anyway), plus using a proper VS command window with all environment variables set correctly: start `Developer Command Prompt for VS2013` from the start menu, then for example `msbuild /path/to/solutionorproject /p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild` to rebuild the release version

Comment: Hi, to use MSBuild option do I need to set any environment settings in the system path. If so, what I need to add in the system path. Thanks